# Convert string "20-May-07" to date and manipulate

Tags: perl, datetime

In my perl program, I am calculating warranty start date from warranty end date The difference is 3 years. Following is the chunk of code that I have written so far:

```
use Time::ParseDate;
use DateTime;
use POSIX;
use DateTime::Duration;

my $warranty_expiration_string = "20-May-07";
my $epoch = parsedate($warranty_expiration_string);
my $warranty_expiration = strftime "%D", localtime($epoch);   # returns: 05/20/07
```

How do I deduct 3 years from `$warranty_expiration` to get `$warranty_start` date? 
I tried,

```
$warranty_start->subtract(DateTime::Duration->new('years' => 3));
```

..but it did not work.

Comment: Please define "did not work".

Comment: [Time::ParseDate](http://p3rl.org/Time::ParseData) can't parse `20-May-07`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand all the different date/time modules being mixed. You only need some of them, not all of them. If you want to do date math using [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) anyway, you want something like this:

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $dateparser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => '%d-%b-%y' );

my $warranty_expiration = $dateparser->parse_datetime($warranty_expiration_string);
my $warranty_start      = $warranty_expiration->clone->subtract( years => 3);
```

Most of the DateTime::Format::* modules are meant to be used with DateTime and I prefer to use those if I can.

You may also want to read more about the ongoing DateTime project and the list of recommended modules at:

- http://datetime.perl.org

Comment: For the last line of your code, I got this error: Can't call method "clone" on an undefined value

Comment: Then your input is not in the format you say it is. You can add the `croak` option on DateTime::Format::Strptime like: `DateTime::Format::Strptime->new( pattern => '%d-%b-%y', croak => 1)` and your program will die with an error message. There are other alternatives for the error handling. See [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime::Format::Strptime) for details.

Answer (score 2):

`$warranty_expiration` isn't a DateTime, it's a string. You want to do something like:

```
my $warranty_expiration = DateTime->from_epoch(
    epoch => $epoch,
    time_zone => 'local',
);
my $warranty_start = $warranty_expiration->clone->subtract(years => 3);
```

and then you can use `$warranty_expiration->strftime("%D")` and `$warranty_start->strftime("%D")` as formatted strings. Also, if you use one of the `DateTime::Format` modules instead of `Time::ParseDate`, you will get back a `DateTime` directly from the parser instead of having to use `from_epoch`.

Comment: I tried your code. But its is giving me an error: The 'epoch' parameter (undef) to DateTime::from_epoch did not pass regex check
 at /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DateTime.pm line 461, <$csv_fh> line 1.

Comment: @rad Then find out why `$epoch` is undef and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

No need to instantiate `DateTime::Duration` for this as the calculation methods expect those parameters directly:

```
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now->subtract(years => 3);
print "$dt\n";
```

Result:

```
2009-08-30T14:36:27
```

Comment: This code can work for the current date, what about custom date  like 20-May-07 ?

Comment: @rad, it works with any DateTime object, no matter what date it represents.