# what Perl will take to compare in this case?

Tags: perl, operators

Just interested at this kind of comparison, any clue?

Say there are two variables as below:

```
$p1 = "2013-01-11/2013-01-04";
$p2 = "2013-01-12/2012-01-05";
```

If like below codes in Perl,

```
if $p1 lt $p2
```

What Perl will take to compare and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`lt` is string comparation operator, and it compares two operands in their literal sense.

In your case, two strings

```
2013-01-11/2013-01-04
||||||||||
2013-01-12/2012-01-05
```

will be compared in the illustrated manner, and stop at the 9th position (the first position characters are different, also note string index starts at 0), i.e. `1` in `$p1` and `2` in `$p2`. And also `1` is less than `2` literally. So `$p1 lt $2` is true.

Comment: Very easy-understanding answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Breaking down your tasks:

- separate your strings into (start_stringtime, end_stringtime) string pairs
- convert each string in the string pair into a datetime
  (there's a [gazillion modules](http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/03/13/datetime.html) for this, choose one(s) appropriate for your task)
- calculate the time periods for each pair
- compare the time periods numerically - `if $p1 < $p2`

This question:
[Convert string "20-May-07" to date and manipulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199284/convert-string-20-may-07-to-date-and-manipulate)

will give you some leads